# haproxy remap tcp port with single backend

Tags: haproxy

I'm using haproxy in tcp mode.  I have a single frontend that listens to several ports:

```
frontend front
   mode tcp
   bind *:20000
   bind *:20001
   ...
   default_backend back
```

And a single backend that forwards these requests without changing ports:

```
backend back
   server myserver server.host.com check port 20000
   server anotherServer another.host.com check port 20000
   server mybackup backup.host backup.host.com check port 20000 backup
   # some other useful backend logic, like logging
   # which I don't want to repeat a bunch of times
```

Because we are supporting some legacy APIs, we need to accept some old, lower level ports and remap them.  For example, I want to accept port `200` and remap it to `20000`, `201` to `20001`, etc.

I was hoping for a frontend directive to change port like you might do for a header in http mode, but I can't find one.  Will have have to abandon my nice clean single backend?

Answer (score 1):

I would go about using 2 backends if I were you.

If you insist, you can use the `use-server <server> if <condition>` option and test `dst_port`.

Something like: `use-server bla20001 if dst_port 201` or something like this.

Comment: I wish it were only two backends!  There are probably up to 10 ports I will be listening to.  Thankfully the haproxy configuration will be created dynamically based on the ports provided in the application configuration, but I was still hoping that the resulting configuration would stay slim.

Comment: Did you try the `use-server` thing?

Comment: Nah, I just ended up creating loads of front-ends.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no good way to do this.  I ended up creating more frontends and backends.